# Web server failed to start and port 10086 was already in use in IntelliJ IDEA 2021

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Web server failed to start and port 10086 was already in use in IntelliJ IDEA 2021. There is nothing output in terminal when I run `netstat -ano |findstr 10086`. What's wrong here?
Any help?

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> netstat -ano |findstr 10086
PS C:\Windows\System32>
```

console output:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 10086 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 10086 or configure this application to listen on another port.
 (LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.java:40)
```

Comment: *Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 10086 or configure this application to listen on another port.* - what more to do?

Comment: @ScaryWombat How to find the process that's listening on port 10086 on Windows? I get nothing output in terminal with this command `netstat -ano |findstr 10086`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please make sure you are typing in the console correctly.

[image]

[image]

**Not working check example**

If you don't want the embedded server to start, just set the following property in you application.properties (or .yml):

```
  spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-embedded-web-servers

If you application really is a Web application, then you can easily change the port using the server.port property (in your application's .properties/.yaml file, as a command line argument at startup, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the other unused port using the server.port as follow in the application.properties

`server.port = 10087`

Comment: You don't need to restart the OS. you just need to restart the application after changing the port

Comment: I have changed the port to start application, but it still throw port already in use with new server.port. Maybe there is something wrong in OS or IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: the port you have specfied is already used by the other process. Before changing the port make sure that it is unused. You can check the same using the `netstat -ano | findstr:<port>`